# How to reveal generic type

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have the following generic type definition:

```rb
# typed: true
class A 
  extend T::Sig 
  extend T::Generic 
  Value = type_member

  sig { params(value: Value).void }
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end 

  sig { returns(Value) }
  def value 
    @value 
  end
end
```

When I reveal the type of `#value`, I'm expecting it is `Integer`, but it's `T.untyped`:

```rb
v = A.new(42)
T.reveal_type(v.value) #=> Revealed type: T.untyped https://srb.help/7014
```

I understand it's possible to specify the type of the argument explicitly `A[Integer].new(42)`, but that way I can't put keep type information separately in `.rbi` file.

What is the right way annotating generic types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A[Integer].new(42)` is the right way to specify generic type.

You probably expect sorbet to infer type Integer from the input (42). However, sorbet doesn’t work that way. You have to specify the generic type as A[Integer] and sorbet will use that to validate the type of the input (42) and output (@value) at run time.

> I understand it's possible to specify the type of the argument explicitly A[Integer].new(42), but that way I can't put keep type information separately in .rbi file.

It is probably impossible to separate type construct (or sorbet construct) and your code cleanly like that for generic type. As you’d see even for T::Array or T::Hash, you also have to specify the type the same way. And for constant, you’d frequently need to use T.let.

Comment: What's the difference between generic type and generic parameter?  For example, I can infer the method's return type from its input argument: https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%20%0A%0Asig%20do%20%0A%20%20type_parameters(%3AT)%0A%20%20.params(value%3A%20T.type_parameter(%3AT))%0A%20%20.returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BT.type_parameter(%3AT)%5D)%0Aend%0Adef%20build_array(value)%0A%20%20%5Bvalue%5D%0Aend%0A%0AT.reveal_type(build_array(42))%0A

Comment: AFAIK generic parameter only works for a single function. A `type_parameter` is inferred at run time when the function is triggered, and goes away with the context of the function. Generic type is tied with the class and applicable in multiple context, so it's harder for them to infer and kept in memory.
 
Generic type support is still very rudimental at the moment. Sorbet.org doesn't have full documentation of how they work so a lot of this is from trial and error.